# Type in a combobox and find like values vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox

Currently I have a dropdown list that has thousands of values.  Right now when I type in the dropdown list it will find the values that start with the letters I have typed and filter the list.  Is it possible to find all values that contain the text?

Example:

Lets say the dropdown list contains: Barron, Barron Inc, Barron Corp, The Barron Corporation, The Bar, The Barn Yard, 1-800-Flowers, American Horror Story, Random, Values.

Right now when I type "Bar", the list filters to Barron, Barron Inc, Barron Corp.  What I need to have the list do is display, Barron, Barron Inc, Barron Corp, The Barron Corporation, The Bar, The Barn Yard - Everything that contains bar.  I have done a little research and I have come up empty.  Any thoughts?

Comment: As far as I know the standard ASP.Net Ajax combobox and the AutoCompleteExtender only match words begining with the typed filter. There are other controls sold by other that can do what you need. If you need to do this from scratch then you will need some sort of web service that will return a list based on your filter... If you have a large list then you may want to delay your call until there is a minimum of say 3 or 4 letters.

Comment: This is a windows application, not web based.  I probably should have mentioned that in the original post.  If it was web based, I could possibly use javascript.  Thank you though.

Comment: Sadly, there's no build-in way to to this. Either write this functionality yourself, use third party controls (like Infragistics), or use one of the many solutions you can find online, like e.g. this: [ComboBox with Suggest Ability based on Substring-Search](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/631196/ComboBox-with-Suggest-Ability-based-on-Substring-S)

Comment: Ah.. understand. And yes JS would also do the job! OK so what are you using to populate your combi?

Comment: Thank you @DominicKexel I do have access to Infragistics, so I might go that route.

Comment: @Mych I am using a dataset to populate the dropdown, with a clientname and clientid.

Comment: @JohnJanssen Cool. You have to set `AutoSuggestFilterMode` to `AutoSuggestFilterMode.Contains` on the `UltraComboBox` to get the desired behaviour.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: @DominicKexel It works perfectly!  Thanks.  If you want to answer the question, I will give you a plus 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you have access to the [Infragistics](http://www.infragistics.com/) control collection, you can use a `UltraComboBox` and set its [`AutoSuggestFilterMode`](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~AutoSuggestFilterMode.html) to `AutoSuggestFilterMode.Contains`.